# moving the armature along with the model

Tags: rigging, armature

The armature doesn't move along with the model when I move it around but still poses.[image]

Comment: Try to move the root bone instead of the mesh

Answer (score 4):

Simply move the armature object, or the root bone (in pose mode).

[image: Moving a rigged object]

Once you have rigged a character, you no longer need to move the mesh objects themselves (usually characters consist of several mesh objects). That would be very difficult to animate, and could not deform.

This is in fact the purpose of rigging - to allow you to easily control and animate a character using bones rather than the original objects themselves.

Usually a rig will have a *Master* or *Root* bone that is used to position, rotate and possibly scale the character. This bone is the final parent of all the bones in the rig (the first bone of each chain, if not parented to something else, is parented to the root)

Comment: What about the IK solvers? If you move the base without the IK targets, the armature deforms. I suppose you could select the IK targets too but doesn't seem very efficient.